# Xubuntu recently started to report crashes about Web content

Tags: crash

I am using Xubuntu 18.04 with the 5.3 kernel and `btrfs` filesystem.

Recently I start getting crash reports like this:

```
ProblemType: KernelOops
Annotation: Your system might become unstable now and might need to be restarted.
Date: Tue Jun 16 10:28:42 2020
Failure: oops
OopsText:
 BUG: Bad page state in process Web Content  pfn:2269a4
 page:ffffe6d7c89a6900 refcount:-1 mapcount:-1 mapping:0000000000000000 index:0x1
 flags: 0x17ffffc000000a(referenced|dirty)
 raw: 0017ffffc000000a dead000000000100 dead000000000122 0000000000000000
 raw: 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 fffffffffffffffe 0000000000000000
 page dumped because: PAGE_FLAGS_CHECK_AT_PREP flag set
 bad because of flags: 0xa(referenced|dirty)
 Modules linked in: vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) snd_hda_codec_hdmi nvidia_uvm(POE) edac_mce_amd snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic nvidia_drm(POE) ledtrig_audio ath5k nvidia_modeset(POE) kvm_amd ath ccp snd_hda_intel kvm nvidia(POE) snd_intel_dspcfg mac80211 snd_hda_codec irqbypass snd_hda_core usblp snd_hwdep input_leds snd_pcm cfg80211 serio_raw wmi_bmof snd_seq_midi libarc4 k10temp snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi drm_kms_helper drm snd_seq ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler snd_seq_device fb_sys_fops snd_timer syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt asus_atk0110 snd sch_fq_codel mac_hid soundcore hwmon_vid parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 btrfs xor zstd_compress raid6_pq libcrc32c hid_generic usbhid hid uas usb_storage pata_acpi pata_atiixp i2c_piix4 ahci r8169 libahci realtek wmi
 CPU: 3 PID: 3049 Comm: Web Content Tainted: P    B      OE     5.3.0-59-generic #53~18.04.1-Ubuntu
 Hardware name: System manufacturer System Product Name/M5A78L LE, BIOS 2101    04/02/2015
 Call Trace:
 
Package: linux-image-5.3.0-59-generic 5.3.0-59.53~18.04.1
SourcePackage: linux
Tags: kernel-oops
Uname: Linux 5.3.0-59-generic x86_64
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it is related to `btrfs` filesystem. I had this sort of problem with Chrome too before, but it looked differently. Chrome didn't start at all.

I cleared Firefox cache and it seems that crashes have stopped.

Now I removed the `.mozilla` directory, created it again and set `nodatacow` attribute on it by

```
sudo chattr +C ~/.mozilla
```

I am not sure that this is a real solution, bet we'll see.

It is always recommended to set this attribute on browser caches, but I forgot this time.

Comment: It looks like the issue is fixed now.